# MongoDB : extremely huge log file?

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

I have set up MongoDB (on windows) a while ago to listen to WebSockets. Recently, I was checking the size of the dataset I had collected so far. The total size of my data folder where the collections are stored is about 7GB now. Then, I discovered that surprisingly the size of the log file is 175GB (!!!). For now, I just used the rotate command to generate a new log file and delete the old one. But of course, I am curious as to why this extremely large log file is generated. I checked the content of the file. Amongst the millions (or billions?) of lines of messages, here are a few examples of how the messages typically look:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-27T01:52:07.723+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20883,   "ctx":"conn298926","msg":"Interrupted operation as its client disconnected","attr":{"opId":33104664}}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-27T01:52:07.723+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn298926","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:61724","uuid":"88da63c3-37dc-416f-a044-dcc3eae36d8b","connectionId":298926,"connectionCount":39}}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-27T01:52:07.726+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20883,   "ctx":"conn298929","msg":"Interrupted operation as its client disconnected","attr":{"opId":33104670}}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-27T01:52:07.727+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn298929","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:61727","uuid":"7fc3e5c7-5687-474f-aa0e-c83f501c16cc","connectionId":298929,"connectionCount":38}}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-27T01:52:07.737+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20883,   "ctx":"conn298932","msg":"Interrupted operation as its client disconnected","attr":{"opId":33104677}}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-27T01:52:07.737+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn298932","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:61730","uuid":"0c8c0ecf-7aef-4bab-980b-267a3a0c78b7","connectionId":298932,"connectionCount":37}}

...
```

It seems, there is some connect-disconnect thing (on various ports?) going on, but I have no idea where this comes from or what causes this.

BEFORE YOU READ ON: a simple question first that may not require going through all the code below; if these messages are not "critical" (meaning they indicate that something is going wrong), is it possible to simply turn them off in logging? That would be a simple solution. From the dataset I have, I see that my script is functioning correctly and the data is accurately collected, so I assume, it could be sufficient to simply turn off the logging messages of this type. READ FURTHER FOR MORE DETAILS...

---

My basic async python code for connecting to the WebSockets and receiving messages looks (shortened) like this:

```py
async def run_socket(manager,subscription=None):

    async with websockets.connect(manager.url) as socket: 

        # receive messages and process
        while True: 

            # receive message
            message = await socket.recv()

            # process data and store
            manager.process_message(message)

    return 

def run_stream(manager,subscription):
    while True: 
        try: 
            # create a new event loop 
            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            loop.run_until_complete(run_socket(manager,subscription))
        except KeyboardInterrupt as e: 
            print(e)
            loop.close()
            return 
        except Exception as e:
            # reconnect in case of exception
            print(e)
            loop.close()
            sleep(5)
    return 

# MAIN LOOP 

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # manager 
    manager = create_websocket_manager(stream)

    threads = []
    for subscription in manager.generate_subscriptions(): 
        print(subscription)

        # create a new event loop 
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

        # create thread for the stream
        thread = threading.Thread(target=run_stream,args=(manager,subscription))
        thread.daemon = False

        # collect threads
        threads.append(thread)

        # run 
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads: 
        thread.join()
```

The function `create_websocket_manager` (not shown here) creates a custom  "WebSocket manager" object that parses and stores the messages that arrive from different streams. All objects share the same base class which (shortened) locks like this:

```py
class WebsocketManager:

    def __init__(self,stream):
        # ... set_collection(self)
        return

    def set_collection(self):
        # ... uri_mongo, db_name, col_name
        self.col = MongoClient(uri_mongo)[db_name][col_name]

    def parse_message(self,message): # -> list
        # ... message -> results
        return results

    def process_message(self,message):
        results = self.parse_message(message)
        if len(results)>0:
            self.col.insert_many(results)
        return
```

The manager sets a collection for the stream (`self.col = MongoClient(uri_mongo)[db_name][col_name]`), then parses and stores the arriving messages to the collection.

The main loop shown further above runs various threads for several streams that are processed by the same manager object. Additionally, I run several python instances of the main loop file for different managers. Maybe the different instances of cmd running the WebSockets are what cause the connect-disconnect thing?

If you read till here, thanks already for going through this long question, and I appreciate your feedback :)

Best, JZ

Comment: "... is it possible to simply turn them off in logging?"  Probably.  How is `mongod` launched?  [There are several levels of logging that you can control](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#systemlog-options "Link to mongod systemlog options -->").

Comment: Log rotation might be handy here: https://www.sitelint.com/blog/flush-delete-or-empty-mongodb-log-file/